# Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal - Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

estaba intentando generar una consulta SQL para adquirir datos.
En un principio la aplicacion java que usaba de prueba funcionaba perfectamente.
Cuando genere el proyecto web y realice la consulta en el servlet seguia funcionando (impropia los datos en consola)
Cuando los pase al JSP dejo de andar y comenzo a tirar el siguiente error(imagen 1)
no tengo idea de como solucionarlo. Tengan en cuenta que soy bastante nuevo asi que puede que este cometiendo errores bobos. Pero busque en varios foros y no encuentro una solucion.

[image: Actualmente no puedo hacer funcionar la aplicacion de prueba tampoco.]

les dejo mi codigo

```
package com.mycompany.pruebacomic;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author OUTLET
 */
public class NewMain {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        String user     = "root";
        String password = "";
        String bd       = "proyecto_comic";
        String host     = "localhost";
        String port     = "3306";
        String timeZone = "UTC";

        String url;

        Connection con;
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;

        String sql;

        //jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/comics_db?user=root&password=""&serverTimezone=UTC

        url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + bd + "?user=" + user + "&password=" + password + "&serverTimezone=" + timeZone;

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

            System.out.println("Driver cargado correctamente!");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection( url );

            System.out.println("Conectado satisfactoriamente");

            sql = "SELECT * FROM `comic` WHERE com_cat_id = cat_id AND com_est_id = est_id AND com_autor_id = autor_id AND com_user_id = user_id";

            stm = con.createStatement();

            rs = stm.executeQuery( sql );

            ArrayList<Comic> listaComics = new ArrayList<>();

            while( rs.next() ){

                Comic comic = new Comic();

                comic.setComicTitulo(rs.getString("com_nombre"));

                Categoria categoria = new Categoria();
                categoria.setCatID(rs.getInt("cat_id"));
                categoria.setCatNombre(rs.getString("cat_nombre"));
                comic.setComicCategoria(categoria);

                Autor autor = new Autor();
                autor.setAutorId(rs.getInt("autor_id"));
                autor.setAutorNombre(rs.getString("autor_nombre"));
                comic.setComicAutor(autor);

                Estado estado = new Estado();
                estado.setEstadoId(rs.getInt("est_id"));
                estado.setEstadoNombre(rs.getString("est_nombre"));
                comic.setComicEstado(estado);

                User usuario = new User();
                usuario.setUserId(rs.getInt("user_id"));
                usuario.setUserName(rs.getString("username"));
                usuario.setUserPass(rs.getString("user_pass"));
                usuario.setUserNombre(rs.getString("user_nombre"));
                usuario.setUserEmail(rs.getString("user_email"));
                usuario.setUserFoto(rs.getString("user_foto"));
                usuario.setUserDescripcion(rs.getString("user_desc"));
                comic.setComicUser(usuario);

                comic.setComicDescripcion(rs.getString("com_descripcion"));
                comic.setComicFecha(rs.getDate("com_fecha"));
                comic.setComicFoto(rs.getString("com_foto"));
                comic.setComicId(rs.getInt("com_id"));






                listaComics.add(comic);                

            }

            stm.close();
            rs.close();
            con.close();

            mostrarTodosLosComics(listaComics);


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error al cargar el Driver de MySQL");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error al conectar con la BD");
            System.out.println( ex.getMessage()  );
        }

    }

    static void mostrarTodosLosComics( ArrayList<Comic> comics ){

        //Version 2
        for(Comic unComic: comics){

            System.out.println( unComic.getComicTitulo()  );

        }

    }

    static void mostrarUnComic(Comic comic){
        System.out.println( "" );
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entra a las propiedades de tu proyecto desde Netbeans (click derecho , propiedades) y especifica la clase principal en la seccion de "RUN". Suerte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]